# What is the meaning of PRZS?

Tags: meaning, abbreviations, acronyms

In Robert Conquest's limerick

> There was plenty of good-natured chaff
>   When I popped in to fuck the giraffe,
>   And the PRZS
>   Could hardly suppress
>   A dry professorial laugh.

what does PRZS mean?

Answer (score 5):

**P**resident of the **R**oyal **Z**oological **S**ociety